# Having trouble displaying a list of transactions to a list box in VisualStudios2019 winforms C#

Tags: c#, list, winforms, display, box

I know I'm butchering the transaction class. I just have no idea what to do. Nothing gets displayed when I run the form and hit add new transaction. I appreciate any help here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AccountBalance
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnNewTran_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strTransactionType = "";
            if (rbDeposit.Checked)
            {
                strTransactionType = rbDeposit.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                strTransactionType = rbWithdrawal.Text;
            }



            Transaction newTransaction = new Transaction();
            newTransaction.Amount = decimal.Parse(txtTAmount.Text);
            newTransaction.Type = strTransactionType;
            newTransaction.Date = txtTDate.Text;
            lstTransactions.Items.Add(newTransaction);



            decimal decBalance = decimal.Parse(lblCBalance.Text);
            if (newTransaction.Type == "Deposit")
            {
                decBalance += newTransaction.Amount;
                lblCBalance.Text = decBalance.ToString("c");
            }
            else
            {
                decBalance -= newTransaction.Amount;
                lblCBalance.Text = decBalance.ToString("c");
            }



            if (decBalance < 0)
            {
                lblCBalance.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            }



            rbDeposit.Checked = false;
            rbWithdrawal.Checked = false;
            txtTAmount.Clear();
            txtTDate.Clear();
            txtTAmount.Focus();
        }



        private void btnRemTran_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int intSelectedIndex = lstTransactions.SelectedIndex;
            Transaction selectedTransaction = (Transaction)lstTransactions.SelectedItem;
            lstTransactions.Items.RemoveAt(intSelectedIndex);



            decimal decBalance = decimal.Parse(lblCBalance.Text);
            if (selectedTransaction.Type == "Deposit")
            {
                decBalance -= selectedTransaction.Amount;
                lblCBalance.Text = decBalance.ToString("c");
            }
            else
            {
                decBalance += selectedTransaction.Amount;
                lblCBalance.Text = decBalance.ToString("c");
            }



            if (decBalance >= 0)
            {
                lblCBalance.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }



        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            rbDeposit.Checked = false;
            rbWithdrawal.Checked = false;
            txtTAmount.Clear();
            txtTDate.Clear();
            txtTAmount.Focus();
        }



        private void lstTransactions_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Transaction selectedTransaction = (Transaction)lstTransactions.SelectedItem;
            if (selectedTransaction.Type == "Deposit")
            {
                rbDeposit.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                rbWithdrawal.Checked = true;
            }
            txtTAmount.Text = selectedTransaction.Amount.ToString("c");
            txtTDate.Text = selectedTransaction.Date;
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }

    public class Transaction
    {
        internal decimal Amount;
        internal string Type;
        internal string Date;
    }
}
```

```
namespace AccountBalance
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.lblTDate = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtTDate = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lblTAmount = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtTAmount = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lblTType = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.rbDeposit = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.rbWithdrawal = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.rbServFee = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton();
            this.lblPayee = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtPayee = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lblCheckNum = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtCheckNum = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lblCBalance = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtCBalance = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lstTransactions = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
            this.btnNewTran = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnRemTran = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnClear = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnExit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // lblTDate
            // 
            this.lblTDate.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblTDate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 9);
            this.lblTDate.Name = "lblTDate";
            this.lblTDate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 13);
            this.lblTDate.TabIndex = 0;
            this.lblTDate.Text = "Date of Transaction:";
            // 
            // txtTDate
            // 
            this.txtTDate.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 25);
            this.txtTDate.Name = "txtTDate";
            this.txtTDate.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtTDate.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // lblTAmount
            // 
            this.lblTAmount.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblTAmount.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(263, 9);
            this.lblTAmount.Name = "lblTAmount";
            this.lblTAmount.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 13);
            this.lblTAmount.TabIndex = 0;
            this.lblTAmount.Text = "Transaction Amount:";
            // 
            // txtTAmount
            // 
            this.txtTAmount.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(266, 25);
            this.txtTAmount.Name = "txtTAmount";
            this.txtTAmount.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtTAmount.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // lblTType
            // 
            this.lblTType.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblTType.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(473, 9);
            this.lblTType.Name = "lblTType";
            this.lblTType.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 13);
            this.lblTType.TabIndex = 0;
            this.lblTType.Text = "Transaction Type:";
            // 
            // rbDeposit
            // 
            this.rbDeposit.AutoSize = true;
            this.rbDeposit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(481, 28);
            this.rbDeposit.Name = "rbDeposit";
            this.rbDeposit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(61, 17);
            this.rbDeposit.TabIndex = 3;
            this.rbDeposit.TabStop = true;
            this.rbDeposit.Text = "Deposit";
            this.rbDeposit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // rbWithdrawal
            // 
            this.rbWithdrawal.AutoSize = true;
            this.rbWithdrawal.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(481, 51);
            this.rbWithdrawal.Name = "rbWithdrawal";
            this.rbWithdrawal.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(78, 17);
            this.rbWithdrawal.TabIndex = 4;
            this.rbWithdrawal.TabStop = true;
            this.rbWithdrawal.Text = "Withdrawal";
            this.rbWithdrawal.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // rbServFee
            // 
            this.rbServFee.AutoSize = true;
            this.rbServFee.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(481, 74);
            this.rbServFee.Name = "rbServFee";
            this.rbServFee.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(82, 17);
            this.rbServFee.TabIndex = 5;
            this.rbServFee.TabStop = true;
            this.rbServFee.Text = "Service Fee";
            this.rbServFee.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // lblPayee
            // 
            this.lblPayee.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblPayee.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 53);
            this.lblPayee.Name = "lblPayee";
            this.lblPayee.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 13);
            this.lblPayee.TabIndex = 0;
            this.lblPayee.Text = "Payee:";
            // 
            // txtPayee
            // 
            this.txtPayee.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 71);
            this.txtPayee.Name = "txtPayee";
            this.txtPayee.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(230, 20);
            this.txtPayee.TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // lblCheckNum
            // 
            this.lblCheckNum.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblCheckNum.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(263, 53);
            this.lblCheckNum.Name = "lblCheckNum";
            this.lblCheckNum.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(81, 13);
            this.lblCheckNum.TabIndex = 0;
            this.lblCheckNum.Text = "Check Number:";
            // 
            // txtCheckNum
            // 
            this.txtCheckNum.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(266, 71);
            this.txtCheckNum.Name = "txtCheckNum";
            this.txtCheckNum.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtCheckNum.TabIndex = 7;
            // 
            // lblCBalance
            // 
            this.lblCBalance.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblCBalance.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 109);
            this.lblCBalance.Name = "lblCBalance";
            this.lblCBalance.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(86, 13);
            this.lblCBalance.TabIndex = 0;
            this.lblCBalance.Text = "Current Balance:";
            // 
            // txtCBalance
            // 
            this.txtCBalance.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(145, 102);
            this.txtCBalance.Name = "txtCBalance";
            this.txtCBalance.ReadOnly = true;
            this.txtCBalance.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.txtCBalance.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // lstTransactions
            // 
            this.lstTransactions.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.lstTransactions.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 125);
            this.lstTransactions.Name = "lstTransactions";
            this.lstTransactions.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(439, 316);
            this.lstTransactions.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // btnNewTran
            // 
            this.btnNewTran.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(460, 171);
            this.btnNewTran.Name = "btnNewTran";
            this.btnNewTran.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 23);
            this.btnNewTran.TabIndex = 8;
            this.btnNewTran.Text = "New Transaction";
            this.btnNewTran.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // btnRemTran
            // 
            this.btnRemTran.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(460, 252);
            this.btnRemTran.Name = "btnRemTran";
            this.btnRemTran.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 23);
            this.btnRemTran.TabIndex = 9;
            this.btnRemTran.Text = "Remove";
            this.btnRemTran.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // btnClear
            // 
            this.btnClear.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(460, 333);
            this.btnClear.Name = "btnClear";
            this.btnClear.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 23);
            this.btnClear.TabIndex = 10;
            this.btnClear.Text = "Clear";
            this.btnClear.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // btnExit
            // 
            this.btnExit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(460, 414);
            this.btnExit.Name = "btnExit";
            this.btnExit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(99, 23);
            this.btnExit.TabIndex = 11;
            this.btnExit.Text = "Exit";
            this.btnExit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(578, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnExit);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnClear);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnRemTran);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnNewTran);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lstTransactions);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtCBalance);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblCBalance);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtCheckNum);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblCheckNum);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtPayee);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblPayee);
            this.Controls.Add(this.rbServFee);
            this.Controls.Add(this.rbWithdrawal);
            this.Controls.Add(this.rbDeposit);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblTType);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtTAmount);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblTAmount);
            this.Controls.Add(this.txtTDate);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblTDate);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTDate;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtTDate;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTAmount;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtTAmount;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblTType;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rbDeposit;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rbWithdrawal;
        private System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton rbServFee;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblPayee;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtPayee;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblCheckNum;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtCheckNum;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblCBalance;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtCBalance;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ListBox lstTransactions;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnNewTran;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnRemTran;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnClear;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnExit;
    }
}
```

I pretty much tried to use quick fixes and watched some random videos and came up with nothing.

Comment: The list box has no idea how to display your transaction. To start, you could provide a `public override string ToString()` method in the `Transaction` class.

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add your items to the `ListBox` directly. Create an appropriate list and bind that to the `ListBox`, then add your items to that list. If you use a `BindingList<Transaction>` then adding an item to the list will automatically update the bound control, which will not happen with a `List<Transaction>`.

```cs
var transactions = new BindingList<Transaction>();

myListBox.DataSource = transactions;
```

By default, when you add an item to a `ListBox`, `ToString` is called on that object and the result displayed. If you don't override the `ToString` method, that will just be the name of the type. You can set the `DisplayMember` of the `ListBox` and the specified property value will be displayed, e.g.

```cs
var transactions = new BindingList<Transaction>();

myListBox.DisplayMember = nameof(Transaction.Amount);
myListBox.DataSource = transactions;
```

Note that only properties can be specified as the `DisplayMember` or `ValueMember`. Fields will not work.

If you want some custom text displayed then you need to override the `ToString` method and have it return the desired text.